# Application contacting web service more than necessary

Tags: android, listview

I have an listview that contacts a web service whenever it is called and this is what it looks like

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_DATA_WEB = "data";
     private String stringxxx;
     ProgressDialog pDialog;
     LoadAllData mTask; 

            JSONArray question = null;          
            android.widget.ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

        stringxxx = getIntent().getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");


        questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

    mTask = new LoadAllData();

         mTask.execute();

        }


    @Override   
    protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

          HashMap<String, String> item = questionList.get(pos);

          Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
          i.putExtra(TAG_DATA_WEB, item.get(TAG_DATA_WEB));
          startActivity(i);

            }     

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {              
        /** If user Pressed BackButton While Running Asynctask
            this will close the ASynctask.
         */
        if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }          
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, PREV.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

     if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
     {
        mTask.cancel(true);
      }  

        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

     if (pDialog != null)
     {
         if(pDialog.isShowing())
         {
             pDialog.dismiss();
         }
            super.onPause();

      }  
}

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();             
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();           
}
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {  
            pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){ 
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) { 
                    mTask.cancel(true); 
                    Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, PREV.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
            } 
        });

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {

                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

                    json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return json;           

            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { 

                try {

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < DT.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = DT.getJSONObject(i);


                    String data = question.getString(TAG_DATA_WEB);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_DATA_WEB, data);

                    questionList.add(map);

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                                R.layout.listelements,
                                new String[] { TAG_DATA_WEB }, new int[] {
                                R.id.Subject,});

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }


    }

}
```

The problem I have is that when I click on an item on the listview to go to the next activity, it does as its suppose too with no problem its just when I pressed the back button to go back the listview, the listview activity restarts and it also contacts the web service again to retrieve the information like as if I put `finish();` after `startArtivity(I);` in the `onItemClick` part of the code. Now normally this wouldn't be a problem if you web service didn't have a search limit but the one i am using does. So basically what Im saying is that when the user clicks on an listview item to go to the next activity and when they press the onBack button, I want the information to still be there instead of the application contacting the web service again to retrieve information and the end result will be the search limit being reached. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used XML parsing so I can probably give you help logically.

- You can use bean class with get and set methods and store the results
  you get from web service.
- Use Set methods to store the values where you have written the
  parsing code.
- Use get methods in your activity's adapter code to retrieve those
  values.
- This way web service won't be called again when you reach that
  activity using back button.
- But remember, if you launch that activity with service again from its parent, web service will be called again.

Answer (score 0):

You would have several options:

Replace the AsyncTask data loading with an AsyncTaskLoader data loading. Check the Loader developer article first. I dropped using AsyncTasks for data loading long time ago...

The scond option is to store the data you receive and don't call the webservice next time. For this, store the data somehow in `onSaveInstanceState` and in `onCreate` check if Bundle parameter is not null and if you have data set there for th same key you used in `onSaveInstanceState`. If true, you already have the data. If false, query.

Depending on data importance and volatility you could save it once in some kind of app persistence (shared preference or sqlite) once you downloaded it and use it every time the activity recreates or creates itself.